# My Wi-Fi & mobile network location is horribly wrong!

Tags: wi-fi, geolocation

I have enabled network location to use features of google now on my phone- here's what happens, once or twice a week: instead of my location, which is Milan, Italy, I see myself (and get advice for restaurants, museums, currency exchange) in Belgrade, Serbia. 
If I turn on my GPS, then I "get back" home. If, with only network location active, I try to find my phone, it is always at the same address, over 2000 miles away, in a different country. 
How does this happen? Should I worry about this? I find no possible way to ask Google if it is their problem- any advice? 
Thank you!

Simona

Answer (score 0):

It may be your wifi proxy, some wifi routers connect to a network from another country, meaning your GPS thinks your'e in another country due to the connection.